# weak pointer to NSData cannot read data using NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5.1

I don't truly understand the difference between weak and strong pointer.
It doesn't cause any big problem until now I am following an example in the documentation, making an NSURLRequest and use it in NSURLConnection to received data.

The code is like this:

```
    //create the request with url
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/students.json"]];

    //create the with the request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    if (connection) {
        //create NSData instance to hold data if connection is successfull
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
//        NSLog(@"%@",@"Connection successfully");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@",@"Connection failed");
    }
```

SO I append data into `receivedData` in the body of delegate method.

`@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;`

```
//delegate method
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"%@",@"Receiving Data");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.receivedData length]);
}
```

the code I posted above is working:) because I have just fixed it.

**My question is** - The type of the pointer was original `weak`. I would always get 0 bytes of data from `[self.receivedData length]` before I have changed the type of pointer from `weak` to `strong` and I don't understand why it can't **hold** the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A weak reference doesn't hold onto its contents.  You were telling the `receivedData` variable to look at the mutable data object you created, but not to hold onto it.  So when that `if` block completed, the data's scope ended and ARC released it; there was nothing else holding onto it so it was deallocated and receivedData was set to nil, because it no longer had anything to point to. `[self.receivedData length]` returned 0 (technically nil) because `self.receivedData` was nil.  By declaring receivedData strong, you told it to hold onto the object it points to, making sure it stays around until you're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

try to use that to fetch the data

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:3000/students.json"]]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *strResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//    NSLog(@"%@",strResponse);

SBJSON *sbJason = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *getNameList = [sbJason objectWithString:strResponse];
```

Comment: deligates are not calling this way. any reason?